# Rich Text Box in android

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any control in android which we can use as a rich text box which can handle formatting of characters such as bold, italic etc. and use fonts and color ?

If anyone having any link or source related to the above information please share it with me.

Answer (score 6):

`SpannableString` class or `HTML.fromHtml()` allows you to manipulate different styles in actual string. See the links below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml(android.text.Spanned)

Answer (score 1):

Sample `SpannableString` and `TextView` implementation:

```
TextView tv = new TextView;
String text = "String String String String body";
SpannableString spannableStr = new SpannableString(text);
spannableStr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0 , 10, 0);
tv.setText(spannableStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

WebView is the closest that I can think of, but it is super duper heavy unless you want the entire screen to be a webview.