# Simple RichText Editor in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

i want to create a simple rich text editor in android, just like this application on google play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spn.richnotepad&hl=en

and i am very new in android so anyone can provide some idea about it.
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found some quick solutions :

- [droid-writer](http://code.google.com/p/droid-writer/)
- [cwac-richedit](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit)

Also check following discussions:

- [Rich Text Box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7952117/3419997)
- [Implementing a rich text editor in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4283755/3419997)

Answer (score 11):

It's not difficult at all but before you start I highly recommend you to read the guide from Android Developer site:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html 
You will learn how to save data which is a very important part of your project.

Then you have to learn all about **EditText** (allows the user to type text into your app) and **TextView** (displays text on screen).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

When your app is finished you can add some additional functionality:

- Spelling Suggestions 
  https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/index.html
- Text Formatting 
  http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring
- Font Style 
  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601

Some useful links: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

I also advice you this **Notepad Tutorial** which will guide you step by step to construct a simple notes list that lets the user add new notes. 
http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Check out this one https://github.com/chinalwb/Android-Rich-text-Editor, it is still in progress but you may get some pointers from there. Thanks.

### Supported styles:

1. Bold
2. Italic
3. Underline
4. Strikethrough
5. Numeric list
6. Bullet list
7. Align left
8. Align center
9. Align right
10. Insert image
11. Background color
12. Hyper link
13. @
14. Quote
15. Foreground color
16. Emoji icon
17. Superscript
18. Subscript
19. Font size
20. Video
21. Image from internet
22. Dividing line
23. All styles support save as HTML file
24. Set init html content and continue editing or displaying

**Demo for part of the supported features**

[image: Demo for part of the supported features]