# Underline text while typing in EditText - Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-animation

I am new to android development and was working on a project which involved in underlining specific words in the text field while typing I found an example on dribble which achieves the same thing:

[image: Dribble Image]

Here I have the index of the word in the string which I want to underline. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you

> **Please Note: I don't want to know about how to find the `substrings` as mentioned in the video but I want to achieve the same underline animation as shown in the video**

Is there any way that we can have a canvas behind the `EditText` and then have the underline animation there??

Comment: I am not sure about the same animation which looks like a custom one for sure, but I found a repo with the same built-in animations for texts: https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView

Comment: But it is applied on the whole string and not a word. I would like to have the underline style to a specific word

Comment: You will need a kind of rich text editor so this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283755/implementing-a-rich-text-editor-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736316/12053756