# Custom Edit Text with different text emphasis and opacity

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make an **Edit Text that can have a regular, bold and italic and bold italic text at the same time** and also can have different opacity like that in WhatsApp Chat's Edit Text.

I search on internet but  can't find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several examples for android rich edit text.
It might helpful for you.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit

https://github.com/chinalwb/Android-Rich-text-Editor

https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

And several answers in here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736316/10247147

[image]

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.chinalwb:are:0.1.7'
```